# Eclipse not showing graphics on my computer, but does on other computer

Tags: java, eclipse

So here's the issue.

My laptop(lenovo y500, 650m Sli) is my work horse computer that i use for everything like gaming and what not, and now java programming with eclipse.

I created a snake game project , but when ever i attempt to run it, the window shows up as blank and then i "lose game" because i can't see anything displayed. I thought the problem may be with the code, but when i sent it to my other computer, it rendered everything without any problems.

So what can it be? I've attempted to change my graphics driver, reinstalled, ran with intel graphics...no luck.

Any ideas?

thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code ? People here are not magicians. If you want us to be able to help you, please post the shortest code allowing you to reproduce the problem.

Comment: the code is pretty long. Should i just post the entire thing? i found some free code sources online that work, but not on  my lenovo.

Comment: heres the link: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/snake/

Comment: You have to reduce the size of the code, to get a *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*, see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve